# Azure Functions CRON expression not supported?

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

We have a need to run a function only during weekdays from 9am to 7pm. Using a CRON expression builder we have come up with this CRON expression to represent the schedule we need:

*0 0/5 9-19 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *

It's a valid CRON expression but the function is not firing at all. Are there limitations to the complexity of CRON expressions Azure timer triggered functions can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions), Azure Functions uses [NCronTab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) library to interpret CRON expressions. I don't see the `?` character in the list of supported characters. Try replacing it with `*`.

Comment: I did realise it's NCRON only after posting. I used a CRON builder...There is no NCRON builder but at least I found this validator if anyone is interested https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/